# How can I run a node.js server next to the current PSK setup?

Tags: node.js, express, browser-sync, polymer-starter-kit

I need to listen to POST requests on the `/mail` path toso that I can send e-mails via JS, without refreshing the page. I was thinking about an express nodejs server which will send the email when a POST request is made on `/mail`.

The `gulp serve` task currently uses browserSync to display the application, but this only displays the static part of the site. 
If I run `gulp serve` and then I run the `node mail.js` script which contains an express server, I get an `EADDRINUSE` error, because the express server is in conflict with browserSync, I think.

What can I do to overcome this error?

Answer (score 0):

In your mail.js file, change the port number from 3000 to anything else. like 4000
(here app is your express instance)

```
 app.listen(3000, function( ....
```

to
    app.listen(4000, function( ....

This may result in CORS error when you post to ?mail now.

So you now need to add in your express server code add allowance for POST requests from localhost:3000 app by using something like below

```
app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost:4000");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```